# Mongodb subquery in insert

Tags: mongodb

I search for make something like :

```sql
insert into B (col)
select id from anotherCollection limit 1
```

I test this, but I suspected it was not going to work :

```js
db.B.insert([
  {
    "a": "lores ipsum",
    "b": [
      db.getCollection('anotherCollection').find({},{_id:1}).limit(1)
    ]
  }
]);
```

is it necessary to use a projection ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in mongo dbbut in javascript or python like this

```
var a = db.getCollection('anotherCollection').find({},{_id:1}).limit(1)
db.B.insert([
  {
    "a": "lores ipsum",
    "b": a
  }
]);
```

Comment: yeah this solution work but it seems strange to me not to be able to use a lookup or something like that